# Generate Csharp file from schema (xsd)

Tags: c#, xsd

I generate this schema with xsd.exe

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:smp="http://iso.org/abc" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://iso.org/abc" version="1.0.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name ="InternalAddress" type="smp:InternalAddressType"></xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name ="Letter" type="smp:LetterType"></xsd:element>
       </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>    
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:complexType name="AddressType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Line1" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Line2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="InternalAddressType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:restriction base="smp:AddressType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="Line1" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:simpleType name="LetterType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z]"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Result:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://iso.org/abc")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://iso.org/abc", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class root {

    private InternalAddressType internalAddressField;

    private string letterField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public InternalAddressType InternalAddress {
        get {
            return this.internalAddressField;
        }
        set {
            this.internalAddressField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Letter {
        get {
            return this.letterField;
        }
        set {
            this.letterField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://iso.org/abc")]
public partial class InternalAddressType : AddressType {
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(InternalAddressType))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://iso.org/abc")]
public partial class AddressType {

    private string line1Field;

    private string line2Field;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Line1 {
        get {
            return this.line1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.line1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Line2 {
        get {
            return this.line2Field;
        }
        set {
            this.line2Field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In the Csharp code, InternalAddressType type derives all element from AddressType without restrictions although I suppress "Line2".
Is there any way to generate Csharp code with the restrictions in the schema?

Answer (score 1):

No, your XSD allows something that is not allowed with C#. Inheritance demands you can access every `public` member from base classes.

There is no way to hide members from deriving classes when using inheritance.

Comment: @truccam: need more help? If not, please accept the answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: At least, such member should be ignored by attributes   [XmlIgnore(), System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]

Comment: Indeed. Do you need more help? If not, please don't forget to accept the answer.